# Cycling selected class to ul > li with load more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

This is supposed to be simple, but there are unexpected behaviors occurring everywhere!

I have a list structured as following

**HTML**

```
<ul class = "question-list">
    <li class="question"> something </li> 
    <li class="question"> something </li>
    <li class="question"> something </li>
    <li class="question"> something </li>
    <li class="question"> something </li> //Shouldn't this be li:last-child?
    <a class="load-more" href="#">Load More</a>
</ul>
```

The list shows 5 posts by default, then loads 5 more when `a.load-more`is clicked until all posts are loaded. When all posts are loaded, `a.load-more` is disappeared. This is how the DOM is rendered by default.

**JS**

```
Template.foo.onRendered( function() {
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 74) { //Keydown J
        var listItem = $('ul.question-list > li.question');
        var listItemFirst = $('ul.question-list > li.question:first-child');
        var selectedChild =  $('ul.question-list > li.question.selected-child');

        if($('input').is(":focus")|| $('textarea').is(":focus")){
            return null; //Do not activate when input or textarea is focused
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(! $(listItem).hasClass('selected-child')){
                $(listItemFirst).addClass('selected-child'); //select first child if ul > li has no selected item
            } else
            if( $(listItemFirst).hasClass('selected-child')) {
                $(listItemFirst).removeClass('selected-child');
                $('ul.question-list > li.question:last-child').addClass('selected-child'); //if first child is selected, select last child
            } else { 
                selectedChild.removeClass('selected-child');
                selectedChild.prev().addClass('selected-child');  // if above all is not the case, select previous li
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

The JS does what it's commented.

Now this should work as it is, but I am encountering the following problems.

- When navigated away and back, order of li selection is messed up. (i.e., selected in order of second, fourth, third, one. Fixed when refreshed)
- If there are more posts to be loaded, last child will not select.

**EDIT 1**

Problem 2 is solved (Thanks @Fabrizio Calderan). I moved the `a.load-more` out of the ul. However, when navigated out and back, the order of selection is messed up.

Comment: try to close the `<ul>` before the "load more" link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the "Load More" link out of the UL. A UL should contain only LI elements.

Then, in the keydown handler, you will find it much simpler to :

- find the currently selected LI element and remove className "selected-child" from it
- calculate the index of the LI you want to select
- add className "selected-child" to the LI with the calculated index.

```
Template.foo.onRendered( function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
            c = 'selected-child',
            $listItems, $selected, index;
        if (keyCode == 74) { //Keydown J
            if($('input').is(":focus") || $('textarea').is(":focus")) {
                return;
            } else {
                $listItems = $('.question-list li');
                $selected = $listItems.filter('.' + c).removeClass(c);

                // *** to go backwards through the list ***
                index = ($selected.length == 0) ? 0 : $selected.index() - 1;
                if(index < 0) 
                    index = $listItems.length - 1;

                // *** to go forwards through the list ***
                //index = ($selected.index() + 1) % $listItems.length;

                $listItems.eq(index).addClass(c);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I haven't yet accepted your answer yet because for some reason, the order is still messed up when I navigate away and back...
I have upvoted it though. Also, how would I make this work the same way but the opposite way? I have changed -1 to +1 but I don't understand the code completely to make it choose the first li after switching from last li.

Comment: I'm not sure what might be going on when you navigate away then back to the page. I would need to see a working demo. Cycling forwards through the list is slightly simpler than backwards - see edited code above.